# Sequelize create method returns undefined values

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am using typescript with Sequelize ORM, I have a `User` model which has some type definitions like so:

```
export interface UserAttributes {
  id: number
  name: string
  username: string
  email: string
  ...
}

interface UserCreationAttributes
  extends Optional<
    UserAttributes,
    | 'id'
     ...
  > {}

export class UserModel
  extends Model<UserAttributes, UserCreationAttributes>
  implements UserAttributes {
  id!: number
  name!: string
  username!: string
  email!: string
  ...
}
```

And here is the user model itself:

```
UserModel.init(
  {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    username: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true,
    },
...
}
)
```

When I use the User model like so:

```
async function createUser({...params}) {
 const user = await User.create({...params})
 const {id, name, email, } = user
console.log(name, email) // returns `undefined` `undefined`
return user // id is null when returned but other values are returned
}
```

Also `user.toJSON()` returns the values, but `id` comes back as `null`. How do I rectify this issue? Also, what could be the cause of this? Thank you very much.

Comment: was the user created in the DB?

Comment: Yes the user was created @danu I don't just know why I get those undefined values

Comment: i didnot seen this case, you can update more code to test